# Covariance of absolute value of variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, covariance

I have some relatively complicated variables I am working with.

I need to find the covariance: $\text{cov}(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|)$, is there a simplification of $\text{cov}(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|)$ in terms of $\text{cov}(x,y)$?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $